# How to make grid gap responsible?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a note app, and this is my styling for note grid:

```
.notes-grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(250px, 0.2fr)); 
  gap: 10px;
}
```

grid template columns was
`repeat(auto-fit,minmax(250px, 1fr));` before, but i want to make the gap responsive, not the size of notes.

I set an initial value for gap, and it is 10px. When grid starts to wrap, i want to change gap responsibly to fill blank area.
[I want to spread notes across the width to right of 'note3'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqgzN.png)

Comment: can you at least put a working example so anyone can help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to play with alignment:

```css
.notes-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 0.2fr));
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between; /* added this */
}

.notes-grid > div {
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="notes-grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for solving my problem! It really worked and i didn't think it to be that easy.